# How to change/modify strings different in a list

Tags: python-2.7

I don't know if this question has been asked before, but it seems that I can't find the function that I am looking for. I want to `add two different string to different strings in a list`. Something like this:

```
old_list: ['spider','cat','iron','super','bat']

old_list: ['spiderman','catwoman','ironman','superwoman','batman']
```

So I want some kind of function that changes the strings by adding '`man`' or '`woman`' without making a new list. I think/know it can be done with some kind of `for-loop` but can't seem to find a easy way of doing it. And I am sorry if this question has been asked before, but I can't really find an answer to this specific function.

Answer (score 3):

Slice-assign back into the list.

```
>>> ['{}{}'.format(pref, suff) for (pref, suff) in zip(old_list, itertools.cycle(('man', 'woman')))]
['spiderman', 'catwoman', 'ironman', 'superwoman', 'batman']
>>> id(old_list)
43518144
>>> old_list[:] = ['{}{}'.format(pref, suff) for (pref, suff) in zip(old_list, itertools.cycle(('man', 'woman')))]
>>> id(old_list)
43518144
>>> old_list
['spiderman', 'catwoman', 'ironman', 'superwoman', 'batman']
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is there a more simple way of doing it? I am still new to python and it seems a bit complicated for me.

Comment: You could iterate over the indexes of the elements, but the jury is out on whether or not that is actually "simpler".

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of a simpler answer, I will post this one:

```
for i in range(len(old_list)):
    old_list[i] += suffixes[i%len(suffixes)]
```

Note you can have any number of `suffixes`.